# How to do find and replace for RichTextBox of WPF. I have done it for windows forms RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, replace

I want to know how to do find and replace for wpf `RichTextBox`? I could not get the `.Text` property of `RichTextBox` in WPF. please help me.

Thanks
Laxman

Answer (score 1):

There is a forum post that shows how this is done [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2988ae8-e7b8-4a62-a34f-b851aaf13886#search_text). You'd need to pass the [RichTextBox.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) to the manager shown in that sample code.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. You have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source projects like

https://github.com/keyoti/RapidFindReplaceWPF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173509/A-Universal-WPF-Find-Replace-Dialog